# Yarn script fails when invoking other Yarn-scripts

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I've got an issue when invoking other Yarn scripts from a Yarn-script. What I want to achieve is having one `yarn develop` task that first invokes TypeScript and some other preprocessors before starting a couple of watchers and running my application. I'd like to use `npm-run-all` (or something similar) to invoke multiple targets as that would allow me to define separate targets that I can manually run as well without having duplicate script-entries in my `package.json`.

I've made a minimal reproduction case which has the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "task:one": "echo one",
    "task:two": "echo two",
    "run-all": "npm-run-all task:one task:two",
    "run-all-yarn": "yarn task:one && yarn task:two"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Invoking `yarn task:one` results in an `echo one` as expected, as does `yarn task:two`. If I invoke `yarn run-all` though, I get an error:

```
$-> yarn run-all
yarn run v1.22.10
$ npm-run-all task:one task:two
$ echo one
error Couldn't find the binary echo one
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "task:one" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

`yarn run-all-yarn` fails with (almost exactly, sans the command being executed on the second line) the same error.

If instead of Yarn I use NPM (`npm run run-all`) it all works as expected:

```
$-> npm run run-all

> test@1.0.0 run-all /Users/basdalenoord/Projects/52DN/psyflix/test
> npm-run-all task:one task:two


> test@1.0.0 task:one /Users/basdalenoord/Projects/52DN/psyflix/test
> echo one

one

> test@1.0.0 task:two /Users/basdalenoord/Projects/52DN/psyflix/test
> echo two

two
```

I'm using Yarn version 1.22.17 provided by my node-version from nvm: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/yarn`

I'm a bit lost as to why running individual targets would be fine but combining them fails for yarn, whereas the same script works for `npm`.